# Get the versions of jars,ears and wars and read them programatically in Weblogic server and Glassfish server

Tags: glassfish, weblogic, manifest.mf

My customer wants to get the versions of all deployed modules(jars,war and ear) of web-logic server/glassfish server.

The customer needs a UI, where they need to see the list of  all jars along with the versions of it. They'll be using weblogic and glassfish server.

Is there any industry practice of versioning the jars and monitoring them?

Approach I have tried:

1. While creating a jar, I have included Manifest.MF file that contains the Implementation-Version(key) and the version number(value).
2. Through java weblogic deployment apis, I could get the list of names of deployed modules(like ear, war etc) but I'm stuck in getting the contents of each deployed module.
3. Similarly, I have to write the code for reading in glassfish server

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java and JMX to list all of the deployed apps and version information in weblogic as follows:

```
private static final String RUNTIME_MBEAN_SERVER_JNDI_NAME 
   = "java:comp/env/jmx/runtime";
...
private static MBeanServer getMBeanServer() {
MBeanServer mBeanServer = null;

try {
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    mBeanServer = 
           (MBeanServer) initialContext.lookup(RUNTIME_MBEAN_SERVER_JNDI_NAME);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error connecting to the MBean server", e);
}

  return mBeanServer;
}
```

---

```
public static Map<String, String> getDeployedApplications() {
Map<String, String> deployedApplications = 
       new HashMap<String, String>();

try {
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = getMBeanServer();
    ObjectName domainConfiguration =
           (ObjectName) mBeanServer.getAttribute(
                  new ObjectName(RuntimeServiceMBean.OBJECT_NAME), 
                  "DomainConfiguration");
    ObjectName[] appDeployments = 
           (ObjectName[]) mBeanServer.getAttribute(
                  domainConfiguration, 
                  "AppDeployments");
    for (ObjectName appDeployment : appDeployments) {
        try {
            Object applicationName = 
                   mBeanServer.getAttribute(
                          appDeployment, 
                          "ApplicationName");
            Object versionIdentifier = 
                   mBeanServer.getAttribute(
                          appDeployment, 
                          "VersionIdentifier");
            if (versionIdentifier != null) {
                deployedApplications.put(
                       applicationName.toString(), 
                       versionIdentifier.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Error fetching deploy info for '%s'", 
                   appDeployment), e);
        }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error fetching deployed applications", e);
  }

   return Collections.unmodifiableMap(deployedApplications);
}
```

See the Oracle API for application runtimes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/runtime/ApplicationRuntimeMBean.html)

See more attributes in the JMX deployment docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPRF/api_intro.htm#BHCHIDAC)

And the example above [here](http://steveschols.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/retrieve-deployed-application-information-using-jmx/)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach. 

I could get the versions of the ear s and wars but the main problem here is that I need to print the versions of jars which are inside the ears and wars as well.

I couldn't load the contents of ear and war in the application server based on the name.